# Migrar datos de Base de datos a Base de datos diferente servidor en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

buenas tengo el siguiente panorama

Tengo una base de datos llamada **Mybase** en la cual existe una tabla llamada **mytabla** en un servidor

y tengo otro servidor  en la cual tengo una base de datos llamada  **Mybase2** en la cual existe una tabla llamada **MyTabla2** igual (mismas columnas que la tabla llamada **mytabla**)

anteriormente por que no tenia acceso a la base de datos **Mybase** yo migraba los datos de tabla a tabla con un archivo CSV

pero ahora que tengo accesos  quiero  saber si existe una manera de migrar  directamente los datos  de tabla a tabla

**Las dos bases de datos fueron creadas en MySQL  pero no  están en el mismo servidor**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estás utilizando Windows puedes descargar un software gratuito llamado [Heidi](https://www.heidisql.com/).

Esa herramienta tiene una opción para exportar tu base de datos como un archivo .sql o bien te conecta con el 2do server para que exportes tus datos a otra base de datos que tengas en otro server.

Comment: lo probare de inmediato y te cuento como me fue